# From a dynamic table, save separate tables from the master table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have a dynamic table, something like this (just an example):

```
  var table = '<table>';
  for (var i=0; i<6; i++) {
    table += '<tr>';
    table += '<th>';
    table += 'HEADER ' + i + '</th></tr>'
    table += '<tr><td>one</td>';
    table += '<td>two</td>';
    table += '<td>three</td>';
    table += '<td>four</td>';
    table += '<td>five</td>';
    table += '<td>six</td>';
    table += '<td>seven</td>';
    table += '<td>eight</td>';
    table += '</tr>';
  }
  table += '</table>';
```

What I'd like to do is to take each header and its table data under the header and save each as a separate table. For example, the first table would be:

```
HEADER 0 
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
```

The second table would be:

```
HEADER 1
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
```

etc...

NOTE: There's no guarantee that there's only one row under each header. Some may have multiple rows.

To get the first table I could do:

```
var indexval = $(table).find('tr:contains("1")').index();

var firstTable = $(table).find('tr:lt('+indexval+')');

$('#testarea').html(firstTable);
```

I'm aware I'm calling these "tables" and that may not be correct. But how to start at the "next" header and go the the one after that and save 'that' table? In the end I'd have a number of little tables I could print to the screen by calling their variable names.

## Demo:

```js
var table = '<table>';
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  table += '<tr>';
  table += '<th>';
  table += '<td>HEADER ' + i + '</td></th></tr>'
  table += '<tr><td>one</td>';
  table += '<td>two</td>';
  table += '<td>three</td>';
  table += '<td>four</td>';
  table += '<td>five</td>';
  table += '<td>six</td>';
  table += '<td>seven</td>';
  table += '<td>eight</td>';
  table += '</tr>';
}
table += '</table>';

//$('#testarea').html(table);

var indexval = $(table).find('tr:contains("1")').index();

var firstTable = $(table).find('tr:lt(' + indexval + ')');

$('#testarea').html(firstTable);
```

```css
td, th {
  min-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='testarea'></div>
```

EDIT: I ended up solving my own problem by just using a couple of arrays to store each section of the table (each header and its immediate relevant rows under it). The first for loop gets the index value of the header, and the second for loop selects out the table rows (header and associated cells under it). The "firstRow" variable selects just the first header and its rows, the 'lastRow' variable does the same with the last header and row(s). Apologies for not initially putting the question in clear terms. The question was just asking how to segment out a large table into pieces with each header and its relevant rows underneath and save them as separate variables. My thinking was this would clean up my pagination method I've currently got on my site. When a 'page up' or 'page down' is clicked, it just loads the appropriate variable in the div on the page.

```
var firstRow = "";
var test = [];
var indexVal = [];

for (var i=2; i<7; i++) {
  indexVal[i] = $(table).find('tr:contains('+('MC' + ' ' + i)+')').index();
}   

firstRow =  $(table).find('tr:lt('+indexVal[2]+')');
lastRow = $(table).find('tr:gt('+((indexVal[6]) - 1)+')');

for (var j=1; j<7; j++) {
   test[j] = $(table).find('tr:lt('+indexVal[j + 1]+'):gt('+((indexVal[j]) - 1)+')');  
}
```

The only issue I had was not being able to integrate the first and last rows into the for loops. I had to make them separate hand coded variables. But it works.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shindig/my5xyzwb/155/)

Comment: Read this several times and still can't figure exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: @charlietfl Objective would be for pagination. I've got a large dynamic table with headers that 'start' a new dataset of td's underneath, and I'd like to separate the table into small tables to display in the div one at a time. Page 1, page 2, page 3... Right now my pagination is just grabbing 4 rows per page. But since there's a different number of rows under each header, it's not ideal.

Comment: What does that have to do with the example code which by the way is invalid html with `<th>` wrapping `<td>`?

Comment: Thanks. Fixed the <td> wrap. I'll try and revise the question. Looking at it, it isn't getting at the heart of the matter.